# Develop Reporting Feature

Tags: transactions

Lets say if I want to have method in contract to show all the transactions in which one account requested to deposit tokens to another account during a certain period of time.  How can this be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

I would incline to migrating this concern to front-end clients/servers that connect to the contract, but external to the contract itself.

The contract itself would maintain an authoritative record account transactions and emit events for each state change. In this approach, the contract focuses on the integrity of the authoritative source of information, and does so with a *minimalist* approach.

Given the raw data (via event emitter), consumers of the contract would be free to set up such a query system and optimize it (for scale, performance, changing needs) as required.

Such external (to the contract) processes can include the construction of indexes outside the contract. Note that the external software (contract consumers) can evolve over time potentially becoming quite complex, whereas the contract code is (generally) eternal and therefore needs to perform a handful of critical functions in a perfectly reliable way.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did initially think to use events, but felt as if it is like avoiding the use of blockchain and relying on traditional way of reporting. So thought maybe there is something which I am not yet aware of. Based on this approach can have a event watching code in the web app which will then publish that data to some external DB. All the reporting will be about querying this external DB with the predefined set of indexes to improve the performances. The DB instance should be specific to each node storing the event generated by the transaction performed by that node on the deployed contracts.